# How to place string into an array in c. Also why do i get return from incompatible pointer type error?

Tags: c

My code for creating a StringBundle object is below but essentially i am supposed to place delimiter seperated strings into a dynamically allocated array. My method prints the correct token values for a whole line, but i am not sure why my return value is of incompatable type. below is the struct definition for a StringBundle object. and here is some sample output from my function reading one delimiter-seperated line.

0 901051

1 Becker

2 Locale

3 NM

4 35

5 Eddy

6 015

7 322833N

8 1040812W

9 32.4759521

10 -104.1366141

11

12

13

14

15 959

16 3146

17 Carlsbad East

18 11/01/1992

19

```
/** A StringBundle contains an array of nTokens pointers to properly-
* terminated C strings (char arrays).
*
* A StringBundle is said to be proper if:
* -Tokens == NULL and nTokens == 0
* or
* -nTokens > 0 and Tokens points to an array of nTokens char pointers,
* -each char pointer points to a char array of minimum size to hold
* its string, including the terminator (no wasted space)
*/

struct _StringBundle {
     char** Tokens; // pointer to dynamically-allocated array of char*
     uint32_t nTokens; // dimension of array pointed to by Tokens
};
typedef struct _StringBundle StringBundle;

StringBundle* createStringBundle(const char* const str) {
        char *token, *string, *tofree, *fin, *arr;
        char *strs[20];
        tofree = string = strdup(str);
        int i = 0;

        while ((token = strsep(&string, "|")) != NULL) {
                printf("token = %s\n", token);
                strs[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
                strcpy(strs[i], token);
                //(fin, token);
                i++;
        }

        free(tofree);
        return strs;
}
```

Comment: The function is declared to return a pointer to `StringBundle`, but you return `strs`, which is an array of `char *`. Also, you can't return a local array, which is invalid because the array is destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: It says it right there in the comments: **pointer to dynamically allocated array of char\***. You're not allocating the array dynamically. And you didn't put it into a `StringBundle` structure.

Answer (score 2):

This function is supposed to return a pointer to a `StringBundle` structure, not an array of strings.

That structure needs to contain a dynamically-allocated array of strings. You grow the array using `realloc()`

```
StringBundle* createStringBundle(const char* const str) {
        char *token, *string, *tofree, *fin, *arr;
        StringBundle *bundle = malloc(sizeof StringBundle);
        bundle->Tokens = NULL;
        bundle->nTokens = 0;
        tofree = string = strdup(str);

        while ((token = strsep(&string, "|")) != NULL) {
            printf("token = %s\n", token);
            bundle->nTokens++;
            bundle *temp = realloc(bundle->Tokens, bundle->nTokens * sizeof StringBundle);
            if (temp) {
                bundle->Tokens = temp;
            } else {
                printf("realloc error\n");
                break;
            }
            bundle->Tokens[bundle->nTokens-1] = strdup(token);
        }

        free(tofree);
        return bundle;
}
```

Comment: I think this should be `realloc(bundle->Tokens, bundle->nTokens * sizeof(char*))`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Barmar's answer, if you want to avoid the repeated memory reallocation I suggest to go with a 2-pass approach. Pass 1, determine the number of tokens, pass 2, allocate and fill the struct.
You have to `strdup` the source for each pass since `strsep` is destructive.

```
StringBundle* createStringBundle(const char *str,const char *sep)
 {
    char *token, *dup;
    StringBundle *bundle = malloc(sizeof StringBundle);
    bundle->Tokens = NULL;
    bundle->nTokens = 0;

    // pass 1: get the token count
    dup = strdup(str);
    while (strsep(&dup, sep)) != NULL) bundle->nTokens++;
    free(dup);

    // pass 2: fill the struct
    bundle->Tokens = malloc(bundle->nTokens * sizeof(char*));
    bundle->nTokens = 0;
    dup = strdup(str);
    while ((token = strsep(&dup, sep)) != NULL)
     {
        bundle->Tokens[bundle->nTokens++] = strdup(token);
     }
    free(dup);
    return bundle;
 }
```

Of course `malloc` might return `NULL`. You want to add the error handling yourself.